# can i put the size of an array after its declaration?

Tags: c++

i tried so many things, and since i am a freshman in college, there could be some information out there that could break the limits for me..
                                                                     N 
the main question was to write a program to computer D, where D =  ∑ i=1 (Ai-Bi) , note that A and B are one dimensional arrays.

i tried this

```
<iostream>

main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;

    int a[N];
    int b[N];

    for (i=1; i<=N;i++)
    {
        cin>> a[i]>> b[i];
```

but i realized there's no such thing, i would like to use the knowledge of whom would like to help, and if its a mistake by the author of the problem?

Comment: Yes, use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

If you do `int a[N]`, the array will be allocated at compile time. And, in this case, `N` must have a constant value, which is not true here.

You need to create these arrays dynamically as follows:

```
int *a = new int[N];
int *b = new int[N];
```

Or use `vector<int>` instead:

```
vector<int> a(N);
vector<int> b(N);
```

---

**Edited:** Another problem of your code is you treat the array starting the index at 1, which is 0 actually. You need to change the `for` condition to:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved with a single-pass algorithm that doesn't even need to store any of the values at all, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int a, b; std::cin >> a >> b; )
    {
        total += a - b;
    }

    std::cout << "D = " << total << "\n";
}
```

This will read pairs of integers from the standard input for as long as possible, e.g. until you close the input stream or input something that cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare static array with runtime values. You need to dynamically allocate them like:

```
int* a = new int[N];
```

Don't forget to deallocate at the end with

```
delete [] a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The array size needs to be known at runtime. Thus - you theoretically can't do what you want in a way you want. You can however use the `new` operator:

```
int *a = new int[N];
```

use a vector:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> a;
```

or use a little trick:

```
int N;
cin>>N;
const int M=N;
int a[M];
```

The last one isn't standard behaviour however so better don't try it other than for fun and making code less readable.

Comment: The last example will not compile on a standard-compliant C++ compiler.  It is a VLA.

Comment: It works on devC++ 4.9.9.2 just fine. Would be great if you could explain what "VLA" means, since I only found some local thing with that shortcut + a dutch food product :) DevC++ uses some g++ version.

Comment: VLA - Variable Length Arrays.  It is a non-standard extension (most notably in gcc) - but as it is non-standard, cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. It looked really peculiar in the first place, but added it since it worked. I'll edit the post a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare the size of an array using a variable, try using a pointer. Like:

```
    int *p = new int [N]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't input the size of an array at runtime, instead use a `vector` or try to use `new` and `delete` to create your own implementation of dynamic array.

```
 int size ; 
 cin>> size ; 
 int arr[size] ; // wrong, size must be known beforehand.
```

**Solution1 **

```
Use a vector<int> instead.
```

**Solution2 **

```
  int size; 
  cin>>size ; 
  int * ptr = new int[size] ;
```

**Solution3 **

```
  //declare a maxSize(maximum limit that you think your array will not exceed) 
  // a bit memory inefficient 
  const int MAXSIZE = 20 ; 
  int arr[MAXSIZE] ;  
   // now  use this array.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
#include <vector>
```

And then in your function:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
vector<int> a(N);
vector<int> b(N);
for (i=1; i<=N;i++)
     cin >> a[i]>> b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int N;
cin>>N;
int a[] = new int[N];
int b[] = new int[N];
```

Its a simpler version than the ones using pointers & vectors.

Note: Its always a better way to start from index 0 than from 1,as not all compilers will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone whom helped me, we didn't actually reach new functions in our studies yet, but i looked it up after you told me, it was more clarifying for how arrays work..
i did it in different ways, like declare the sizes as constants first
and then the vector, new, and delete functions..
BIG THANKS